# Ayuda con diseño de Tabs en HTML con Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

En realidad no sé mucho de diseño, por eso utilizo `Bootstrap` para diseñar la parte estética de mi sistema.

Estoy intentando organizar mis `TABs` pero la verdad se me ve de una forma muy horrible, espero que me puedan ayudar indicándome cómo puedo hacer para que se vea más estético, por ejemplo utilizar mas el `div` y que no se parta en 2 partes las letras.

PRODUCTOS LCN -> boton ver mas

[168.235.83.190/~app/img/lcn/public_html](http://168.235.83.190/~app/img/lcn/public_html)

Les dejo la imagen y el codigo de mi `TABS`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="portfolioModal-20" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel-12" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content text-white">
            <div class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr"><div class="rl"></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="container col-md-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Accesorios</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Acopladores</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Control de Accesos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Control Remoto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Entradas Binarias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Estación Climática</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gateways</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Módulos de Bus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Salidas</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si estás usando Bootstrap, entonces por qué no intentas usar uno de los tabs, o menús, o navbar, que te provee Bootstrap por defecto, en lugar de crear uno nuevo?

Comment: el problema no esta en el div si no en el css que esta usando

Comment: http://168.235.83.190/~app/img/lcn/public_html/ en la parte Productos LCN en el boton VER MAS les sugiero que lo vean gracias

Comment: por favor, no pongas links que muy probablemente en un par de semanas no existan mas.. Agrega toda la informacion relevante a tu pregunta apra que en el futuro le pueda servir a alguien mas.

Comment: El tipo de estética que te resulto se debe a que son mucho los items de ese menú horizontal, podrías considerar otra alternativa de menú como lo mencionan arriba en los componentes de la pagina de bootstrap, o puedes utilizar una propiedad en tu menú para que tenga overflow scroll para que el limite horizontal de tu menú no limite el espacio y genere un segundo renglón en los items con mucho texto. Con gusto te ayudo con eso! solamente que me gustaría que ese modulo lo subieras a un Codepen.

Comment: Iván, hace unos minutos edité tu pregunta corrigiendo errores ortográficos y de redacción. La idea es que **no reviertas** dichos cambios.

Comment: Es un ip de prueba si se mejora o se responde a la pregunta se elimina y por eso dejo la imagen, el link es algo relvante para ahora en el momento puedan ver

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores debes tener en cuenta que el menú de Bootstrap intenta ser lo más adaptativo posible, eso afecta al contenido de cada uno de los items de tu menú.

Porque? Por la cantidad de items, yo sugiero que conviertas tu menú horizontal en vertical. Porque no cuadra el hecho de hacer los items del menú scrollable, aunque si **realmente** necesitas el menú así ... No hay de otra.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/76020/6046

Answer (score 2):

Puedes optar por quitar la clase `nav-justified` para que cada pestaña ocupe un tamaño en función de su contenido o dividir en varias filas los tabs.

Esta segunda opción es bastante mala ya que únicamente se verá correctamente en ciertas resoluciones perdiendo la capacidad responsive de tu interfaz.

Las opciones que sugiere la propia documentación de bootstrap son:

- Reducir la cantidad o el tamaño (ancho) de los tabs
- Ocultar algunos elementos en función de la resolución utilizando las clases de bootstrap
- Modificar el punto en el que se pasa del modo "collapsed" al "horizontal" modificando la variable `@grid-float-breakpoint`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Accesorios</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Acopladores</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Control de Accesos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Control Remoto</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Entradas Binarias</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Estación Climática</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gateways</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Módulos de Bus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Salidas</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Accesorios</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Acopladores</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Control de Accesos</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li><a href="#">Control Remoto</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Entradas Binarias</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Estación Climática</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li><a href="#">Gateways</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Módulos de Bus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Salidas</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando clases que pertenecen al elemento modal de boostrap.

En su lugar usa navbar, puedes ver los ejemplos [aquí](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: al usuario le falto colocar el css por lo tanto es complicado resolver el problema sin el css

Comment: 168.235.83.190/~app/img/lcn/public_html vete a PRODUCTOS LCN -> boton ver mas

Comment: ah? lo tienes en un servidor  web?

Comment: si lo tengo en mi hosting

Comment: coloca el fondo blanco

Comment: el background de la pagina colocalo blanco y aparecera las opciones del menu, debe ser que el menu esta transparente

Comment: las letras te salen asi debido a que el texto de los otros es largo, te recomiendo que aumentes el top o el pading de la pagina

Answer (score 1):

Puedes guiarte de este menú que yo hice,

```css
body{
    background: #8999A8;
}
.navbar, .dropdown-menu{
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
border: none;

}

.nav>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li{
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover,.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:focus, .nav .open>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  background: none;
}
.navbar a, .dropdown-menu>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .navbar-toggle{
 color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-menu{
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow:none;
}

.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+1), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+1){
  border-bottom: #C4E17F 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+2), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+2){
  border-bottom: #F7FDCA 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+3), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+3){
  border-bottom: #FECF71 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+4), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+4){
  border-bottom: #F0776C 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+5), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+5){
  border-bottom: #DB9DBE 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+6), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+6){
  border-bottom: #C49CDE 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+7), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+7){
  border-bottom: #669AE1 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+8), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+8){
  border-bottom: #62C2E4 3px solid;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
    color: #fff;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="">Home</a></li>
                        <li class=" dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Departments <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class=" dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">View Departments</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
                        <li class=" dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Managers <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">View Managers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class=" dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Staff <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">View Staff</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Bulk Upload</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class=" down"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">HR <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Change Time Entry</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li class=" dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Signed in as  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nota: el menú está trasparente, colócale un color a tu gusto. Probablemente salgan algunos errores, normalmente es el Padding el que suele fallar, el width y algunos elementos mas.

Answer (score 0):

Saliendome un poco de Bootstrap podría darte una alternativa, ahora bien. Ésta alternativa no es optimizada, pero igual puedes adaptarla.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weBPLb

El menú está vertical y es accesible desde un botón para que aparezca / desaparezca.

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="insider">
        <h5 class="text-center">Menú de navegación</h5>
        <ul class="items">
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Item más largo</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Item aún más largo</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Otro item</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Ésto no acaba</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Hasta cuando</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Deténte</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Super increíble</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Oh my God!</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Save us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Save us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Save us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">NOW!</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Último y más largo ítem</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-danger abrirMenu form-control">Abrir / Cerrar</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu{
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #0275d8;
    padding: 12px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.menu .insider{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    background-color: #0275d8;
}
.menu .insider h5{
    color: #1591ff;
}
.menu .insider ul.items{
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto
}
.menu .insider ul.items .item{
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

**jQuery / JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ven = $(window);
    var inn = $(".menu .insider");
    var abierto = false;
    $(".menu").css({
        "width": 240,
        "height": ven.height()
    });
    $(".menu .insider ul.items").css({
        "height": (ven.height() - 24) - $(inn).find('h5').height()
    });

    $(".menu").css({
        left: ($(".menu").width() * -1) - 100
    });

    function an(){
        if (!abierto){
            abierto = true;
            $(".menu").animate({
                display:'block',
                opacity:1,
                left: 0
            }, 1000, "easeOutExpo");
        }else{
            abierto = false;
            $(".menu").animate({
                display:'',
                opacity:'',
                left: ($(".menu").width() * -1) - 100
            }, 1000, "easeOutExpo");
        }
    }

    $(".abrirMenu").on('click', function(event) {
        an();
    });
  ven.resize(function(){
    $(".menu").css({
      "width": 240,
      "height": ven.height()
    });
    $(".menu .insider ul.items").css({
      "height": (ven.height() - 24) - $(inn).find('h5').height()
    });
  });

});
```

> **NOTA**: Yo uso jQuery 3, jQuery UI & Bootstrap 4 en éste ejemplo.

Adicionalmente: Si te gustan las animaciones y quieres saber más de ellas en jQuery UI hay muchas más: https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Espero pueda servirte.